# How to plot figures in VSCode in a silent manner?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

I am new to VSCode and have a question related to the plotting issues. When I plot a large number of figures, like 100, how to plot silently and prevent figures jumping out one by one? I would appreciate it very much if you could give me some suggestions on this.

Comment: Is there a tool in VSCode similar to the SciView mode in Pycharm?

Comment: you can plot them in the notebook or interactive window, by changing the matplotlib backend with `%%matplotlib backend_name_or_none`

Comment: Can you give an example to explain what you want more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

You can read this issue on [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/10559).

This feature actually exists already in our Jupyter Notebooks editor.

Or you can define Jupyter-like code cells within Python code using a `# %%` comment:

```
# %%
msg = "Hello World"
print(msg)
```